# HTML5 Video loading slow and only seems to work in Chrome

Tags: html, performance, html5-video

I've setup a website with a video automatically being played in the background.
It works, but it seems to only work in Chrome and I need to wait several minutes for it to load.

I first had a 1080p mp4 (47mb) version of the video on my server and tried to play that. Took me several minutes to load, also when I left the site and went back on it, the video didn't load anymore. After putting the index.html on my server again, it started loading again.

After that I tried to use a 720p(11mb) version but the problem was still remaining and the quality seemed like 240p!

I have also looked around on Stack Overflow, but couldn't find a answer for my problem.

This is my current code:

```
<body>
        <div id="center">
        <video width="320" height="400" id="333" autoplay loop="1">         
            <source src="example.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
            <!-- <source src="example.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' /> -->
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>      
         <script>
            var x = document.getElementById("333").volume = 0.2;
         </script>
</body>
```

Stylesheet for it

```
body,html{height:100%}a,a:active,a:focus,body{color:#FFF}html{background-size:contain;background-position:center;background-attachment:fixed;background-repeat:no-repeat}

video {

        position: fixed;

        top: 50%;

        left: 50%;

        min-width: 100%;

        min-height: 100%;

        width: 1300px;

        height: 1300px;

        z-index: -100;

        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

        background-size: contain;

        transition: 1s opacity;     


    }
}
```

What I want to do is, make the video load faster, make Firefox and possible other browsers be able to watch the video and have it in a good quality.

Comment: Well, how fast is your server? What kind of connection does it have to the internet? If you're running this on an old laptop connected over WiFi, that's going to mean slow load times...

Comment: I don't really know how fast my server is tbh. I'm using a desktop pc with wifi.
I'll see if my friends have the same problem and then report back.